# python3.5.2 deleting all matching characters from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following exemple how can i remove all "a" characters from a file that have the following content:

```
asdasdasd \n d1233sss \n aaa \n 123
```

I wrote the following solution but it does not work:

```
with open("testfisier","r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        for index in range(len(line)):
            if line[index] is "a":line[index].replace("a","")
```

Comment: D you want to write it back to the file?

Comment: `filter (lambda x: x is not 'a', "asdasdasd \n d1233sss \n aaa \n 123")` , one of the many possibilities

Answer (score 2):

There weren't any changes because you didn't write it back to the file.

```
with open("testfisier", "r+") as file:
    for line in file:
        for index in range(len(line)):
            if line[index] is "a":
                replace_file = line[index].replace("a", "")

    # Write the changes.
    file.write(replace_file)
```

Or:

```
with open("testfisier", "r+") as f:
    f.write(f.read().replace("a", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regexp substitution. For instance, assuming you have read in the string and named it a_string

`import re 
re.sub('a','',a_string,'')`

This would be one of many possible solutions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
data = open("testfisier").read()
final_data = re.sub('a+', '', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `replace` on a long string. No need to call it on single chars. Also, replace does not change a string, but returns  a new one:

```
with open("testfisier", "r+") as file:
    text = file.read()
    text = text.replace("a", "")  # replace a's in the entire text
    file.seek(0)                  # move file pointer back to start
    file.write(text)
```